# Targeting HTTPS in .htaccess redirect

Tags: .htaccess

I currently have:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain2\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain2\.co.uk [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

for redirecting www. and parked domains to the correct final https url.

Where it fails however is when I enter https://www.domain.com

I am targeting the non secure url in the first line, how do I add support for redirecting www when https is present already.

Also, when I added a subdomain dev.domain.com it redirects to domain.com/dev I'm presuming because of the .htaccess above?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just split the rule into 2 rules-sets.

```
#redirect all domains other than example.com to httpS://example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#redirect none-secure protocol to https
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule (.*) https://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The subdomain should not redirect based on the rules you provided.